# scala - Spark : how to get the resultSet with condition in a groupedData

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Is there a way to the group `Dataframe` using its own schema?

This is produces data of format :

```
Country | Class | Name | age
US, 1,'aaa',21
US, 1,'bbb',20
BR, 2,'ccc',30
AU, 3,'ddd',20
....
```

I would want to do some like

```
Country | Class 1 Students | Class 2 Students
US , 2, 0
BR , 0, 1
....
```

condition 1. Country Groupping.
condition 2. get only 1 or 2 class value

this is a source code..

```
val df = Seq(("US", 1, "AAA",19),("US", 1, "BBB",20),("KR", 2, "CCC",29),
 ("AU", 3, "DDD",18)).toDF("country", "class", "name","age")

df.groupBy("country").agg(count($"name") as "Cnt")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `pivot` function.

```
val df = Seq(("US", 1, "AAA",19),("US", 1, "BBB",20),("KR", 2, "CCC",29),
 ("AU", 3, "DDD",18)).toDF("country", "class", "name","age")
df.groupBy("country").pivot("class").agg(count($"name") as "Cnt").show

+-------+---+---+---+
|country|  1|  2|  3|
+-------+---+---+---+
|     AU|  0|  0|  1|
|     US|  2|  0|  0|
|     KR|  0|  1|  0|
+-------+---+---+---+
```

Comment: I couldn't find a way to rename the columns.

Comment: val rs=df.groupBy("country").pivot("class").agg(count($"name") as "Cnt")
rs.select(col("country"),col("1").as("Class1"),col("2").as("Class2")).show()